# database connection in windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am going through a windows application in C#.net using SQL Server 2008 as database server. The following is the code in my app.config file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myconnection" value="Data Source=ritesh-pc\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Whenever I try to access that key
 `"myconnection" as    string connectionString = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myconnection"];`

the following error occurs

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

Comment: where is the following code??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="myconnection" value="Data Source=mylaptop;Initial Catalog=attendence;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Are you certain that code produced this error. Please post the actual code that produces the error, i.e. the database connect code. That code just loads a string with a value, it doesn't connect to a database.

Answer (score 1):

This could be that your connection string is wrong/inaccessible due to passwords/etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Is a firewall blocking the connection?
- Can you access the database, with the settings in the configuration file, using SQL Server management studio?
- Is the sql database server situated on the same host?
- Can you show us more details, changing some parts obviously (pass/user/host)

Comment: yes, i can access using sql server management studio. yes, it is situated in the same host

Comment: Thankyou nire for a constructive suggestion after all these wild guesses

Comment: why are you adding the connectionstring to the app settings section?
add it to:
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myconnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI"/>
</connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1):

You want something like

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Please refer to [Store connection string in web.config](http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/) I find the article very useful

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error before and what I do is :

[How to resolve Error 26 in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621436/how-to-resolve-error-26-in-sql-server)

I tried using the (IP address of the server)\SQLEXPRESS. Sometimes instance name is unrecognizable  better use the IP address of your sql server.

or maybe you've got a wrong connection string. In your app.config check if the syntax is like this:

```
 <add name="conString"
   connectionString="Data Source=10.99.89.80;Initial Catalog=EWB_FileDownloader;User ID = sa; Password = 12435@"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: This connection string has no instance name at all, only a host (as an IP address). This is just _one_ of many reasons that it might fail, and using a connection string without a instance name will definitely not help.

Comment: @ElectricLlama, This is just a solution if instance name is not recognizable. That the only way you must use the IP Address. And it do work for me

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the connection string , I think you must  set your account parameters (if you have) like this

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=attendence;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

For full details : check [this](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)